# Multiple SPF records for multiple domains

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, microsoft-office-365

We have recently started using Office 365 for our email, which requires us to add a DNS TXT record with the value `v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all`. We already have an `SPF` record with the value `v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com ?all` for Mandrill, an SMTP sender we also use.

[image]

My concern is this might cause some conflict. Is my concern valid or will be be fine with these two SPF records?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can only have one SPF record (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408#section-3.1.2).
You need to combine them like so:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
```

or

```
v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com include:spf.protection.outlook.com ?all
```

Comment: I'm in exactly the same position here... of implementing line 1 or line 2... whats the difference between -all and ?all

Comment: @AdrianSalazar `-all`: mails sent from hosts not specifically allowed are not permitted to send mails. `?all`: means any not specified host is neutral and nothing can be said about the validity of it. In practice it is not sent to spam. `?all` renders the SPF record almost useless. However some 3rd party provides want you to use it because they change IPs often and don't want that to cause problems.

Comment: "You can only have one SPF record." That is clearer than the message I got: " Office 365 ondersteunt slechts één SPF-record" (Office365 only supports 1 SPF-record". It suggested (the way I've read it) like other parties support multiple SPF records, but Office365 doesn't. But as I read your post it's normal just to support 1 SPF record.

Comment: Indeed, each recipient service has a bit of room in the SPF spec in how they want to handle hardfail, softfail, etc.  if Office 365 receives a message, it will only perform one SPF lookup. It also has a configurable option on how to handle SPF hardfail.