# How can I add Mandrill SPF record when using Office365 to manage DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, microsoft-office-365, mandrill

Client's DNS is managed by Office 365. Office 365 helpfully creates an SPF record:

> TXT   @   v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all  1 Hour

Even extra helpfully, this is automatically generated by Office 365 and can't be changed apparently. All I want to do is include Mandrill, but it looks like I'm SOL.

Apart from moving DNS management to another host (which would be painful, but doable), have I got any options?

Comment: (This is a _call Microsoft_ situation)

Comment: Office 365 does DNS?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think so... the OP would need to move DNS or see if MS will [combine the SPF record](http://serverfault.com/a/586011/13325).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no option but to move the DNS records to another hoster.

Microsoft won't allow you to change the SPF record once it's created at their end.

> **Have additional SPF records you want to add for your domain?** If Office 365 manages DNS for your domain, Office 365 handles spam
>   filtering for you. You can't add another TXT record for SPF (spam
>   filtering). To do that, you must set up your domain so that you manage
>   the domain's DNS yourself at an outside DNS host (such as your domain
>   registrar). Then you can set up the SPF record for the domain where
>   you manage DNS for the domain outside Office 365.

Read here for more information: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-edit-custom-DNS-records-in-Office-365-af00a516-dd39-4eda-af3e-1eaf686c8dc9

Comment: Yeah, this appears to be the only option. Shame, as their DNS offering is actually pretty solid. This is one big limitation.